# error-page setting in web.xml doesn't work

Tags: spring, exception, web.xml

In my portlet, I'd like to handle all exception in one way. Config error-type in `web.xml`.
Here is my code in `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

`error.jsp`

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>
no available now!
```

when `nullpointerexception` happens, it doesn't go to my `error.jsp` page.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your error.jsp outside WEB-INF folder say `webapps/contextDIR`

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: For an entire error catch all use `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>`

Answer (score 0):

`location` - location of the resource in the web app **relative to the root of the web application**. Value should start with `/`.

Hence, the file must not be in `WEB-INF`.

Sidenote: I prefer my error pages to be simple HTML pages instead of JSP. What if compiling/rendering the error JSP fails? An error while displaying an error page is not ideal.

If you like this answer you may upvote or accept it.